# Is #inject on hashes considered good style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside the Rails code, people tend to use the `Enumerable#inject` method to create hashes, like this:

```
somme_enum.inject({}) do |hash, element|
  hash[element.foo] = element.bar
  hash
 end
```

While this appears to have become a common idiom, does anyone see an advantage over the "naive" version, which would go like:

```
hash = {}
some_enum.each { |element| hash[element.foo] = element.bar }
```

The only advantage I see for the first version is that you do it in a closed block and you don't (explicitly) initialize the hash. Otherwise it abuses a method unexpectedly, is harder to understand and harder to read. So why is it so popular?

Comment: Why do you think it "abuses a method in an unexpected way"?

Comment: Just pointing out another way: `Hash[ some_enum.map{|e| [e.foo, e.bar]} ]`

Comment: Well, "abuse in an unexpected way" is obviously in the eye of the beholder. My point being: #inject (or any fold operation) will compute a result value from an n-element list. In this case the result is again an n-element collection. This is fine from a theoretical point of view. But frankly, it doesn't smell good in my book - I admit that is a matter of taste. I see this operation more as a "transform each element of collection A into an element of collection B".

Comment: Ruby2.0.0+ has still another way: ```some_enum.map{ |e| [e.foo, e.bar] }.to_h```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  Those with some functional programming background will probably prefer the `inject`-based method (as I do), because it has the same semantics as the [`fold` higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), which is a common way of calculating a single result from multiple inputs.  If you understand `inject`, then you should understand that the function is being used as intended.

As one reason why this approach seems better (to my eyes), consider the lexical scope of the `hash` variable.  In the `inject`-based method, `hash` only exists within the body of the block.  In the `each`-based method, the `hash` variable inside the block needs to agree with some execution context defined outside the block.  Want to define another hash in the same function?  Using the `inject` method, it's possible to cut-and-paste the `inject`-based code and use it directly, and it almost certainly won't introduce bugs (ignoring whether one should use C&P during editing - people do).  Using the `each` method, you need to C&P the code, and rename the `hash` variable to whatever name you wanted to use - the extra step means this is more prone to error.

Comment: The only aesthetic problem with inject approach IMO is the need to explicitly return the hash from the block, as `Hash#[]=` method returns the value assigned, and not the hash itself. I don't know why they omitted to make another method which would do just that.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović: You can use the K combinator (available in Ruby 1.8.7+ under the name `Object#tap`). If you don't have 1.8.7 or 1.9, you can use Marc-André Lafortune's `backports` library. Also, in older versions of `ActiveSupport`, the K combinator used to be available as `returning`. Basically, replace the two lines with this single line `hash.tap {|hash| hash[element.foo] = element.bar }`. (You may want to rename the *inner* `hash` to something else to get rid of the *outer variable shadowed by inner variable* warning.)

Comment: Thanks, `Object#tap` sure can be handy, but here it would arguably only harm readability (and probably performance). I assume it's inevitable in some, purer functional languages?

Comment: i didn't see anything in the wikipedia article that looked like converting an array to a hash. Maybe I missed something? (most of it was in Haskell, which I am really not familiar with) It seems like folds are for when you can apply a single operation to any two values in the list to reduce it down to a single value. What we are doing here is mutating the accumulator. Maybe it is just that this is an impure function that is getting under my skin, but it just doesn't feel right

Comment: Granted, if you're coming from functional programming, the `inject` method may look familiar to you. It is not that I don't understand how it works; my point is that the "straightforward" approach will look straightforward to *all* developers. The `inject` approach will be familiar only to some. 

The argument about the lexical scope seems a bit theoretical though. If you want to do anything with the result, you'll assign it to a variable anyway. (And in Ruby, if you return it directly at the bottom, you don't have to worry about overwriting local vars either)

Comment: @averell: The `each` method will look clearer to all developers, granted. Clarity is important to code quality, but it isn't everything. To take a perhaps extreme example, `for i in 1..10 { accum += i }` is less clear than `accum = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10` (someone with no exposure to programming can understand the second form), but any developer who'd prefer the second form probably isn't programming professionally. Structural symmetry is also important, as is resistance to bugs. `inject` still appears better to me on both of these measures than `each`, for reasons stated but left unchallenged.

Comment: Actually, clarity, even if not everything, ranks pretty high on my list. Secondly, I'd disagree on the point that the reasons stand unchallenged: The first point was that "its a common way to calculate a single result from multiple inputs" - that's probably my biggest gripe, because I see it calculating *multiple* results for a single input. That was the main "dissonance" which prompted my to post this question. Plus, the approach is only common for those familiar with functional programming, and your code *will* be read by those who are not.

Comment: As for the dependency on a variable outside the block: In most cases, you will assign the result of the operation to a variable outside the block anyway. So if you include the variable initialization in your copy-and-paste, the difference will not be as big. Of course, at the end of the day, I prefer a closed method to a variable (e.g. the #tap above looks promising). I just didn't see the `inject` as the right approach over `each`; even though the `inject` approach has less of a clarity problem in the Rails world because it appears to be widely used.

Comment: @averell - FWIW, you don't need to resort to `tap` if you use `hash.update(element.foo, element.bar)` rather than `hash[element.foo] = element.bar` (see 'tiny addendum' below).

Answer (score 30):

As Aleksey points out, `Hash#update()` is slower than `Hash#store()`, but that got me thinking about the overall efficiency of `#inject()` vs a straight `#each` loop,  so I benchmarked a few things:

```
require 'benchmark'
module HashInject
  extend self

  PAIRS = 1000.times.map {|i| [sprintf("s%05d",i).to_sym, i]}

  def inject_store
    PAIRS.inject({}) {|hash, sym, val| hash[sym] = val ; hash }
  end

  def inject_update
    PAIRS.inject({}) {|hash, sym, val| hash.update(val => hash) }
  end

  def each_store
    hash = {}
    PAIRS.each {|sym, val| hash[sym] = val }
    hash
  end

  def each_update
    hash = {}
    PAIRS.each {|sym, val| hash.update(val => hash) }
    hash
  end

  def each_with_object_store
    PAIRS.each_with_object({}) {|pair, hash| hash[pair[0]] = pair[1]}
  end

  def each_with_object_update
    PAIRS.each_with_object({}) {|pair, hash| hash.update(pair[0] => pair[1])}
  end

  def by_initialization
    Hash[PAIRS]
  end

  def tap_store
    {}.tap {|hash| PAIRS.each {|sym, val| hash[sym] = val}}
  end

  def tap_update
    {}.tap {|hash| PAIRS.each {|sym, val| hash.update(sym => val)}}
  end

  N = 10000

  Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
    x.report("inject_store") { N.times { inject_store }}
    x.report("inject_update") { N.times { inject_update }}
    x.report("each_store") { N.times {each_store }}
    x.report("each_update") { N.times {each_update }}
    x.report("each_with_object_store") { N.times {each_with_object_store }}
    x.report("each_with_object_update") { N.times {each_with_object_update }}
    x.report("by_initialization") { N.times {by_initialization}}
    x.report("tap_store") { N.times {tap_store }}
    x.report("tap_update") { N.times {tap_update }}
  end

end
```

And the results:

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------------------------
inject_store             10.510000   0.120000  10.630000 ( 10.659169)
inject_update             8.490000   0.190000   8.680000 (  8.696176)
each_store                4.290000   0.110000   4.400000 (  4.414936)
each_update              12.800000   0.340000  13.140000 ( 13.188187)
each_with_object_store    5.250000   0.110000   5.360000 (  5.369417)
each_with_object_update  13.770000   0.340000  14.110000 ( 14.166009)
by_initialization         3.040000   0.110000   3.150000 (  3.166201)
tap_store                 4.470000   0.110000   4.580000 (  4.594880)
tap_update               12.750000   0.340000  13.090000 ( 13.114379)
------------------------------------------------- total: 77.140000sec

                              user     system      total        real
inject_store             10.540000   0.110000  10.650000 ( 10.674739)
inject_update             8.620000   0.190000   8.810000 (  8.826045)
each_store                4.610000   0.110000   4.720000 (  4.732155)
each_update              12.630000   0.330000  12.960000 ( 13.016104)
each_with_object_store    5.220000   0.110000   5.330000 (  5.338678)
each_with_object_update  13.730000   0.340000  14.070000 ( 14.102297)
by_initialization         3.010000   0.100000   3.110000 (  3.123804)
tap_store                 4.430000   0.110000   4.540000 (  4.552919)
tap_update               12.850000   0.330000  13.180000 ( 13.217637)
=> true
```

`Enumerable#each` is faster than `Enumerable#inject`, and `Hash#store` is faster than `Hash#update`.   But the fastest of all is to pass an array in at initialization time:

```
Hash[PAIRS]
```

If you're adding elements after the hash has been created, the winning version is exactly what the OP was suggesting:

```
hash = {}
PAIRS.each {|sym, val| hash[sym] = val }
hash
```

But in that case, if you're a purist who wants a single lexical form, you can use `#tap` and `#each` and get the same speed:

```
{}.tap {|hash| PAIRS.each {|sym, val| hash[sym] = val}}
```

*For those not familiar with `tap`, it creates a binding of the receiver (the new hash) inside the body, and finally returns the receiver (the same hash).  If you know Lisp, think of it as Ruby's version of LET binding.*

---

Since people have asked, here's the testing environment:

```
# Ruby version    ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
# OS              Mac OS X 10.9.2
# Processor/RAM   2.6GHz Intel Core i7 / 8GB 1067 MHz DDR3
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark.  Strange that `inject_update` is noticeably faster than `each_update`, i wonder why...

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or are these differences tiny, in the region of 1%?

Comment: You are reading wrong: these differences are like 2 or 4 times.

Comment: Anyway, do you know the syntax `Hash[...]` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)?
I've got with that syntax better results than `Enumerable#each`. Something like 20% less consumed time.

Comment: @pablo: right you are!  I've extended the example accordingly -- thanks!

Comment: I know this is a few years old now, but thought I'd point out that in your `insert_update` and `each_update` you're setting the value to the hash rather than the value from the pairs, which I expect makes a difference for the benchmarks. It may be a negligible difference, but for the sake of consistency it may be worth fixing and rerunning the benchmark. It'd also be interesting to see how newer versions of Ruby do with the same test, but not the main point of my comment!

Answer (score 10):

`inject` (aka `reduce`) has a long and respected place in functional programming languages.  If you're ready to take the plunge, and want to understand a lot of Matz's inspiration for Ruby, you should read the seminal *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*, available online at http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/.

Some programmers find it stylistically cleaner to have everything in one lexical package.  In your hash example, using inject means you don't have to create an empty hash in a separate statement.  What's more, the inject statement returns the result directly -- you don't have to remember that it's in the hash variable.  To make that really clear, consider:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8].inject(:+)
```

vs

```
total = 0
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8].each {|x| total += x}
```

The first version returns the sum.  The second version stores the sum in `total`, and as a programmer, you have to remember to use `total` rather than the value returned by the `.each` statement.

One tiny addendum (and purely idomatic -- not about inject): your example might be better written:

```
some_enum.inject({}) {|hash, element| hash.update(element.foo => element.bar) }
```

...since `hash.update()` returns the hash itself, you don't need the extra `hash` statement at the end.

### update

@Aleksey has shamed me into benchmarking the various combinations.  See my benchmarking reply elsewhere here.  Short form:

```
hash = {}
some_enum.each {|x| hash[x.foo] = x.bar}
hash
```

is the fastest, but can be recast slightly more elegantly -- and it's just as fast -- as:

```
{}.tap {|hash| some_enum.each {|x| hash[x.foo] = x.bar}}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `update` be somewhat less efficient than `store` here, because `update` will try to iterate over the given hash (before realizing that there is only one key-value pair)?

Comment: Alexey: Not only are you extremely correct (if there is such a thing, but you've forced me add an entire new response!  See updates...

Answer (score 3):

I have just found in
[Ruby inject with initial being a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434162/ruby-inject-with-intial-being-a-hash)
a suggestion to use [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of `inject`:

```
hash = some_enum.each_with_object({}) do |element, h|
  h[element.foo] = element.bar
end
```

Seems natural to me.

Another way, using [`tap`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
hash = {}.tap do |h|
  some_enum.each do |element|
    h[element.foo] = element.bar
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are returning a hash, using merge can keep it cleaner so you don't have to return the hash afterward.

```
some_enum.inject({}){|h,e| h.merge(e.foo => e.bar) }
```

If your enum is a hash, you can get key and value nicely with the (k,v).

```
some_hash.inject({}){|h,(k,v)| h.merge(k => do_something(v)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with people not fully understanding when to use reduce. I agree with you, each is the way it should be

Comment: Why?  When should one use or not use `reduce`/`inject`/`fold` ?

Comment: you should reduce if you have an expression you can apply that will bring it down to a single value. in this case, we are transforming from one data structure to another, which doesn't really fit, so the example code makes it fit, essentially turning an inject into an each. you could do this with a map as well if you chain a uniq at the end, but that is the same kind of trying to jam a round peg through a square hole, just because you can doesn't make it right.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your reasoning.  The way I see it, `reduce` is defined to take an accumulator and a value, and returns a new accumulator with that value folded in.  It doesn't matter whether the accumulator is a container type or not, or whether information is lost during the "reduction".  In Haskell, list reversal (given `[1, 2, 3]` obtain `[3, 2, 1]`) is implemented according to the standard using a `fold` operation.

Comment: You're right in that it doesn't matter to the function of the accumulator is a container type. However, I personally find it a bit cheeky to say that a function that takes an n-element container as an input and produces an n-element container as an output is "multiple inputs, single output". I don't have any problem believing that the `inject` approach looks the most natural to a functional programmer. I just usually try to make the code readable even for the "humbler" developers. Those that are into Haskell should also be more proficient in figuring out stuff that looks unfamiliar to them ;)