# Ruby inject with initial being a hash

Tags: ruby

Can any one tell me why the following:

```
['a', 'b'].inject({}) {|m,e| m[e] = e }
```

throws the error:

```
IndexError: string not matched
        from (irb):11:in `[]='
        from (irb):11:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):11:in `each'
        from (irb):11:in `inject'
        from (irb):11
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

whereas the following works?

```
a = {}
a["str"] = "str"
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Your block needs to return the accumulating hash:

```
['a', 'b'].inject({}) {|m,e| m[e] = e; m }
```

Instead, it's returning the string 'a' after the first pass, which becomes `m` in the next pass and you end up calling the string's `[]=` method.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to include the m at the end? For example, if the block was `{ |array, (k, v)| array << MyObject.new(k, v) }` would that work? Considering that `array.<<` returns the array.

Comment: @Ziggy: yes, it's necessary because the assignment `hash[key] = value` returns `value`, and you need `hash`.

Comment: @tokland: You saved my day! Without returning result, I was getting erroneous results.

Comment: You can also follow rubocop `Style/EachWithObject` convension and  use `each_with_object`: `['a', 'b'].each_with_object({}) { |e, m| m[e] = e }`

Answer (score 53):

The block must return the accumulator (the hash), as @Rob said. Some alternatives:

With `Hash#update`:

```
hash = ['a', 'b'].inject({}) { |m, e| m.update(e => e) }
```

With `Enumerable#each_with_object`:

```
hash = ['a', 'b'].each_with_object({}) { |e, m| m[e] = e }
```

With `Hash#[]`:

```
hash = Hash[['a', 'b'].map { |e| [e, e] }]
```

With `Array#to_h` (Ruby >= 2.1):

```
hash = ['a', 'b'].map { |e| [e, e] }.to_h
```

With [Enumerable#mash](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Enumerable%3Amash) from Facets:

```
require 'facets'
hash = ['a', 'b'].mash { |e| [e, e] }
```

Comment: Nice alternatives. I especially like the distinction between the original poster's technique and your map-to-pairs-then-create-new-hash approach: the original question is essentially iterating -- for each item, do this operation on the Hash -- so inject seems overly complex (hence the bug). But the mapping approach is more about wholes: make this array of singles into an array of pairs, then make that array of pairs into a hash.

Answer (score 23):

Rather than using inject, you should look into [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

Where `inject` requires you to return the object being accumulated into, `each_with_object` does it automatically.

From the docs:

> Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object given, and returns the initially given object.
>
> If no block is given, returns an enumerator.
>
> e.g.:

```
evens = (1..10).each_with_object([]) {|i, a| a << i*2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

So, closer to your question:

```
[1] pry(main)> %w[a b].each_with_object({}) { |e,m| m[e] = e }
=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b"}
```

Notice that `inject` and `each_with_object` reverse the order of the yielded parameters.