# Array to hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

Input:

```
 a = [[:a, "apple"], [:b, "bear"]]
```

Output:

```
 {:a=>"apple", :b=>"bear"}
```

I think of this way to do it:

```
h = a.inject({}){|dic,i| dic.merge({i[0]=>i[1]})}
```

But I still think it's not the best way. Does anyone have better solutions?

Comment: What you're doing here is creating an entirely new hash for each key-value pair, then create *another* using `merge` for each pair in your list. This is extremely inefficient because of the number of intermediate hashes created will be twice the length of your list. The efficient `inject` version of this should be: `h = a.inject({ }) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] = v; h }`

Comment: Enumerable to hash strikes back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434162/ruby-inject-with-intial-being-a-hash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>> Hash[*a.flatten]
=> {:a=>"apple", :b=>"bear"}
```

Or a prettier one:

```
>> Hash[a]
```

Or after 2.1:

```
>> a.to_h
```

Comment: `Hash[]` is a really awkward name for something that's really handy.

Comment: `Hash[a]` also works in Ruby 1.8.7. So we can pretty much wipe out the ugly hack *+flatten

Comment: @tadman: not that people are not trying to convince the devs to add a method to convert enumerables to hashes. No luck: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/666

Comment: @tokland Thanks. I thought it worked only in 1.9. But it seems a little difference between them though. The order of the elements in the hash is not the same in 1.8 and 1.9. For example,  `Hash[[["a", 100], ["b", 200]]].each` will process `"b"=>200` first in 1.8.

Comment: @halfelf: that's an orthogonal issue. Hashes in 1.9 are orderered, in 1.8.7 they are not. How you build the hash makes no difference. I would reverse the text in the answer (begin with the more important!). "Hash[a], and only if you work with ancient Ruby <= 1.8.6, use this ugly hack" and so on.

Comment: The problem with `Hash[]` is it doesn't take additional arguments like a first-class `to_h` or `to_hash` method would.