# How to write a case statement in Ruby with multiple statements inside a when clause?

Tags: ruby

I tried separating the statements inside the when clauses with commas but it didn't work.

> when 1; statement, statement, statement
>
> when 2; statement, statement, statement

I couldn't find any examples of this online.

```
case selection
when 1
  system "clear"
  view_all_entries
  main_menu
when 2
  system "clear"
  create_entry
  main_menu
when 3
  system "clear"
  search_entries
  main_menu
when 5
  puts "Good bye!"
  exit(0)
else
  system "clear"
  puts "Sorry, that is not a valid input"
  main_menu
end
```

Comment: Yes it actually does work. From your question it isn't clear what's your issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question seems to be "how can I put all those statements on one line to have fewer lines".

Generally, you can use ";" in ruby to replace the End-of-Lines. Thus:

```
case selection
when 1; system "clear"; view_all_entries; main_menu
...
```

Or

```
case selection
when 1 then system "clear"; view_all_entries; main_menu
...
```

Using the ";" in any way is very much not ruby-like and *not* recommended. See below (other answers) for a much nicer refactoring which strips the duplicated code.

Comment: I don't see any point in your first option, with a semicolon after `1`. Nor have I ever seen that used.

Comment: I haven't seen it in code either, per se, @CarySwoveland, but it is valid syntax and shaves a few characters of the line if that is what OP intended.

Answer (score 9):

I would be inclined to write it thusly:

```
if selection==5
  puts "Good bye!"
  exit(0)
end

system "clear"

case selection
when 1 then view_all_entries
when 2 then create_entry
when 3 then search_entries
else        puts "Sorry, that is not a valid input"
end

main_menu
```

Comment: Nice job not being a mindless robot like the rest of us xd

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `when - then` syntax. Note that it is considered bad practice if the lines become too long:

```
case value
when 1 then statement1
when 2 then statement2
when 3 then statement3
when 4 then statement4
end
```

To execute multiple statements for the same condition on the same line you can separate them with `;`. However, this is always considered a bad practice:

```
case value
when 1 then statement1; statement11; statement12
when 2 then statement2; statement21; statement22
when 3 then statement3; statement31; statement32
when 4 then statement4; statement41; statement42
end
```

Comment: Do you know why that's considered bad practice? If `statement1`, `statement11` and `statement12` are all short and together easily fit on one line, it would seem unambiguous. When `Enumerable#reduce` is used, it's common to see `; memo` at the end.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, the cases when the statements are so short are very rare and even then it is more readable on separate lines. Also [the style guide says so](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-semicolon). (:

Comment: @CarySwoveland, can you give such example with reduce?

Comment: I know the style guide says it's a no-no, and I personally don't do it, but as a reader it doesn't cause me a problem if they are confined to a single line.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it's just ugly IMO. Could you give example with `Enumerable#reduce` and `; memo`?

Comment: I just grabbed one [at random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434162/ruby-inject-with-initial-being-a-hash): `['a', 'b'].reduce({}) {|memo,e| memo[e] = e; memo }`. As you know, nowadays `Enumerable#each_with_object` tends to be used instead, in part to get rid of that pesky `; memo`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes, this is unidiomatic use of `reduce` even before `each_with_object` was introduced.

Comment: I don't mean to belabor this, but `when 1 then update_array; save_to_file; log_entry` reads very much like "when 1, update the array, save it to file and log the entry.", so I would not be displeased to find this in someone's code. In fact, I would rather like the shortness of the entire case statement.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, just tried both versions. The multiline still looks better to me. There is indeed a degree of personal taste in the matter.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, as for the `reduce` - prior to `each_with_object` I would have used `Object#tap` instead. IMO reduce should be reducing the collection, not transforming it to another.

Comment: @ndn  and CarySwoveland Thanks for the input guys.  As i said before... i'm still new with ruby and the coding world.  Still learning :)

Answer (score 4):

> i've tried comma, it does not work

Yes, it does:

```
case value
when 1, 2
  "one or two"
else
  "something other than one or two"
end
```

returns "one or two" if `value` is 1 or 2

Comment: He meant how to separate statements (except by newlines).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. It is poor style to chain statements that way, unless you are doing something odd like "ruby -e ...."